# How to iterate over two sets of data and match values in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

What would be the most efficient way to iterate over a data set like this in angular to get a count of how many people are in each city?

```
app.factory('Person', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/person/:id', {id: '@_id'});
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Person', function($scope, Person) {
  $scope.cities = ['Seattle', 'Phoenix', 'Las Vegas', 'Dallas', 'Chicago'];

  $scope.getCount = function(city) {
    Person.query({location: city}, function(data) {
      return data.length;
    });
  };
}]);
```

Show count of people per city

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="city in cities">{{ city }}: {{ getCount(city) }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$scope.people` should be array

Comment: yes sorry, I'm using $resource query() method, so it is returning an array. I'm just not sure how to loop over and get the count.

Comment: If you only need number of people in city, you must only query the count of people, instead of whole array of people. Because there is no need of that array further, Anyways you are returning count of array So array not needed. Try to get city and count of people from API, because it is not feasible to get count for each city via API. Suppose if you have 15 cities, then 15 calls will be fired same time and that will create performance issue.

Comment: Yes that is a good point. I changed the api to return only the count. But I'm still getting the infinite digest error with the function inside the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="city in cities">{{ city }}: {{ getCount(city) }}</li>
</ul>
```

In controller

```
  $scope.getCount = function(city){
      $scope.people = People.query();//you can pass city name here
      return $scope.people.length;
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting an infinite digest loop with this code, any idea why?

Comment: what exactly `People.query();` returning?? an array of objects or an array with values?

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I have right now. To my understanding an array of objects.

Comment: please `console.log(data)` and let me know waht you get

Comment: I'm not able to actually see the console.log because a ton of infinite digest errors are showing up. I'm thinking it has to do with calling the function inside ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the infinite digest errors by just using `angular.forEach` in my controller like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.cities, function(city) {
    Student.query({city: city}, function(data) {
        $scope.count[city] = data.length;
    });
});
```

This still has to hit the API one time per city, I don't know if there's a better way to do this.

I'm going to ask a separate question with this issue.